# $O\left((n^{\frac{3}{4}}+2)\log(n^{\frac{3}{4}}+2)\right)=O(n^{\frac{3}{4}}\log(n))$ for $n\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

In a book, the following is used without explanation:

> $O\left((n^{\frac{3}{4}}+2)\log(n^{\frac{3}{4}}+2)\right)=O(n^{\frac{3}{4}}\log(n))$ for $n\rightarrow\infty$

**proof:**

\begin{align*}
O\left((4n^{\frac{3}{4}}+2)\log(4n^{\frac{3}{4}}+2)\right)&=O\left(4n^{\frac{3}{4}}\log(4n^{\frac{3}{4}}+2)+2\log(4n^{\frac{3}{4}}+2)\right)\\
&=O\left(4n^{\frac{3}{4}}\log(4n^{\frac{3}{4}}+2)\right)\\
&=O\left(n^{\frac{3}{4}}\log(4n^{\frac{3}{4}}+2)\right)
\end{align*}

What is the exact argument to get rid of the $+2$ inside of the logarithm? ... because than it is clear that for $n>1$:

\begin{align*}
O\left(n^{\frac{3}{4}}\log(4n^{\frac{3}{4}})\right)&=O\left(n^{\frac{3}{4}}\log(4)+n^{\frac{3}{4}}\log(n^{\frac{3}{4}})\right)\\
&=O\left(n^{\frac{3}{4}}\log(n^{\frac{3}{4}})\right)\\
&=O\left(\frac{3}{4}n^{\frac{3}{4}}\log(n)\right)\\
&=O\left(n^{\frac{3}{4}}\log(n)\right)
\end{align*}

... is it, that for $n$ large enough $\log(4n^{\frac{3}{4}}+2)\approx\log(4n^{\frac{3}{4}})$ ?
Or am I overlooking the real arumgent?

Comment: We have $\log (4n^{3/4}) < \log (4n^{3/4} + 2) < \log (6n^{3/4})$ for $n>1$. But that constant do not matter in the end.

Comment: My question was: Why exactly the constant do not matter in the end? But i get the short argument you gave: Because: $O(\log (4n^{3/4}))=O(\log(n))$ and $O(\log (6n^{3/4}))=O(\log(n))$ and $\log (4n^{3/4}) < \log (4n^{3/4} + 2) < \log (6n^{3/4})$ implies that $O(\log (4n^{3/4} + 2))=O(\log (4n^{3/4})$) right?

Comment: Yes. It is also similar to how you can omit $2 \log(4n^{3/4} + 2)$, etc. in your arguments in the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding upon my argument in the comments, since $n^{3/4} <n^{3/4} + 2 < 3n^{3/4} $ for $n>1$, we have

$$n^{3/4} \log (n^{3/4}) < (n^{3/4} + 2) \log (n^{3/4}+2)< (3n^{3/4}) \log (3n^{3/4})$$

$$\begin{align}\frac34n^{3/4} \log n < (n^{3/4} + 2) \log (n^{3/4}+2)&< \frac94 n^{3/4} \log n + 3n^{3/4} \log 3\\&<\frac94 n^{3/4} \log n + 3n^{3/4} \log (n^2)\\&=\frac{33}4n^{3/4} \log n\end{align}$$

$(n^{3/4} + 2) \log (n^{3/4}+2)$ is bounded by $Cn^{3/4} \log n$ from both sides.

This shows that $O((n^{3/4} + 2) \log (n^{3/4}+2)) = O(n^{3/4} \log n)$.

Answer (score 1):

"*the* exact argument"?  I don't know about that.  Here's an exact argument.

\begin{align*}
O &{}\left( \left( n^{3/4} + 2 \right) 
\log \left( n^{3/4} + 2 \right) \right)  \\
    &= O \left( n^{3/4} \left( 1 + 2n^{-3/4} \right) \log \left( n^{3/4}(1 + 2n^{-3/4}) \right) \right)  \\
    &= O \left( n^{3/4} \left( 1 + 2n^{-3/4} \right) \left( \log \left( n^{3/4} \right) + \log \left(1 + 2n^{-3/4} \right) \right) \right)  \\
    &= O \left( n^{3/4} \left( 1 + 2n^{-3/4} \right) \left( \frac{3}{4} \log(n) + \log \left(1 + 2n^{-3/4} \right) \right) \right)  \\
    &= O \left( \frac{3}{4} n^{3/4} \log(n) \left( 1 + 2n^{-3/4} \right) + \right.  \\
    & \qquad \left.{}+ n^{3/4} \left( 1 + 2n^{-3/4} \right)\log \left(1 + 2n^{-3/4} \right) \right)  \\
\end{align*}

Then, for $n \geq 1$, $1 \leq 1+2n^{-3/4} \leq 3$, so for $n \geq \mathrm{e}$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{3}{4} &n^{3/4} \log(n)  \\
    &\leq \frac{3}{4} n^{3/4} \log(n) \left( 1 + 2n^{-3/4} \right) + n^{3/4} \left( 1 + 2n^{-3/4} \right)\log \left(1 + 2n^{-3/4} \right)  \\
    &\leq \frac{9}{4} n^{3/4} \log n + 3 \log(3) n^{3/4}  \\
    &\leq \frac{9}{4} n^{3/4} \log n + 3 \log(3) n^{3/4} \log n  \\
    &= \left( \frac{9}{4} + 3 \log 3 \right) n^{3/4} \log n, \quad n \geq \mathrm{e}
\end{align*}

Having shown bounded above and below by $[\text{constant}] n^{3/4} \log n$, it is $O(n^{3/4} \log n)$.

Here's a (perhaps) more direct way, although it is the same "factor out the big part" method.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} &  \frac{\left( n^{3/4} + 2 \right) 
\log \left( n^{3/4} + 2 \right)}{n^{3/4} \log(n)}  \\
    &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + 2n^{-3/4} \right) \frac{ 
\log \left( n^{3/4} + 2 \right)}{\log(n)}  \\
    &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + 2n^{-3/4} \right) \frac{ 
(3/4)\log(n) + \log \left( 1 + 2n^{-3/4} \right)}{\log(n)}  \\
    &= \frac{3}{4} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + 2n^{-3/4} \right) \left( 1+ \frac{\log \left( 1 + 2n^{-3/4} \right)}{\log(n)}\right)   \\
    &= \frac{3}{4}(1+0)(1+0)  \\
    &= \frac{3}{4}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Since this is a constant,
$$  O \left( \left( n^{3/4} + 2 \right) 
\log \left( n^{3/4} + 2 \right) \right) = O\left( n^{3/4} \log n \right)  \text{.}  $$